# Get AudioInputStream from an RTMP stream in Java? Or how to mix audio of multiple RTMP streams

Tags: java, audio, stream, rtmp, javasound

I need to mix the audio streams from multiple RTMP streams. I would like to use the Java Sound API, because it works well for mixing (as discussed in a previous question, [Combining multiple sound streams in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3373628/combining-multiple-sound-streams-in-java?answertab=active#tab-top)) - I have already successfully tried it for files.

I am pretty sure that AudioInputStream should be able to do real-time streams, as is indicated in this FAQ: http://www.jsresources.org/faq_audio.html#ais_length_unknown

What I don't know is how I can get the audio portion of the RTMP stream and get an AudioInputStream from it. Are there any (RTMP) libraries that do that or that I could extend for that purpose?

Any other suggestions on how to mix audio of rtmp streams?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, currently not, I have looked at it but I didn't understand how I would get a stream that I could use like I described above. Maybe I'm just not seeing it, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but I tried to google you an answer and most of the links referred to red5 ;)

Comment: I've been googling and reading related stuff for 3 days, but since I'm new to audio I thought I'd ask here.. maybe someone who's been working with it would know :)

Comment: It's unfortunate, I don't know the answer but I think this is an excellent question, I wish it were getting more attention

Answer (score -1):

ffmpeg library may help you. look in to http://ffmpeg.org. It supports rtmp protocol and also can extract/merge audio streams. You may only need to invoke ffmpeg from your java code.